# Finding a path integral

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Consider a path

$$ L_1 \ : \quad
\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \quad \rightarrow \quad
\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon+i(p+\epsilon) \quad \rightarrow \quad
\frac{1}{2}+i(p+\epsilon). $$

where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small and $p>0$ is fixed.

> **Question:** Find the limit of the path integral
> $$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \Im\left(\int_{L_1} \frac{d}{ds} \log(s(s-1)) \, ds\right)$$

I tried the following:

First thought: Using fundamental theorem of calculus the path integral becomes

\begin{align*}
\int_{L_1} \frac{d}{ds} \log(s(s-1)) \, ds
&= \log\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}+i(p+\epsilon)\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i(p+\epsilon)\right) \right] \\
&\quad -\log\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right)  \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\right) \right].
\end{align*}

Hence we have

$$ \int_{L_1} \frac{d}{ds} \log(s(s-1)) \, ds
= \log\left(-(p+\epsilon)^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)-\log\left(\epsilon^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

So we get

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \Im\left(\int_{L_1} \frac{d}{ds} \log(s(s-1)) \, ds\right) = i\pi-i\pi = 0$$

But my Professor says that the answer should be $\pi$. Please help me.

Comment: Is there a branch cut crossing on the path?

Comment: That doesn't inherently matter; if you cross a branch cut then you cannot just apply FTC from one side to the other.

Comment: Well, where is the branch cut? I guess it's on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Both the start and end points of the path are on the standard branch cut of $\log$. I think the rest of the path gives a number with positive imaginary part as the $\log$ operand so it doesn't actually cross it and the limits are $+\pi i$. But it would probably be worth a more careful integration on parameterizations of most of the path, and take the limits as the endpoints approach the actual full path, to see if there's more going on.

Comment: I won't likely have time for that for a few days, but I'll bookmark this.

Comment: Right now I suspect you're correct and the answer is zero, but the more careful way might give a different answer.

Comment: @aschepler Please tell me the answer. I will then try the question. Is it $\pi$?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: @aschepler Yo said that "rest of the path gives a number with positive imaginary part as the log operand so it doesn't actually cross it and the limits are $+\pi i$ ." How do we get $+\pi i$?

Comment: @Ian Is the answer $\pi$?

Comment: The $+\pi i$ I mentioned are related to the two parts you have in your $i \pi - i \pi = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \log(s(s-1)) \, \mathrm{d}s \right)
&= \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \left( \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s-1} \right) \, \mathrm{d}s \right) \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s} \, \mathrm{d}s \right) + \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s-1} \, \mathrm{d}s \right).
\end{align*}

Now we invoke the following well-known fact that

$$ \operatorname{Im}\left( \int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z - a} \right) = \text{[change of argument about $a$ along $\gamma$]} $$

for any piecewise $C^1$ path $\gamma$ not passing through $a$. This gives

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s} \, \mathrm{d}s \right)
&= \color{blue}{\arctan\left(2(p+\varepsilon)\right)}, \\
\operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s-1} \, \mathrm{d}s \right)
&= \color{red}{-\arctan\left(2(p+\varepsilon)\right)}, \\
\end{align*}

see the picture below as well.

[image: change of argument]

Therefore, we have

$$ \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \log(s(s-1)) \, \mathrm{d}s \right) = 0 $$

and letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ still gives $0$.

Comment: Thank you. But you did not consider the branch of log?

Comment: @Ken, In my calculation I did not use logarithm at all :) You just need to compute the (signed) angle.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s} \, \mathrm{d}s \right)
&= \color{blue}{\arctan\left(2(p+\varepsilon)\right)}, \\
\operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{L_1} \frac{1}{s-1} \, \mathrm{d}s \right)
&= \color{red}{-\arctan\left(2(p+\varepsilon)\right)}, \\
\end{align*}     How did we get the minus sign in second equation?

Comment: @Ken, That's exactly what I am talking about. In the first integral, for instance, as the point $P$ moves along the contour $L_1$, the "argument" of $P$ changes by $\arctan(2(p+\varepsilon))$. (Here, I am not talking about the argument as the function $\arg$. The point is that, the change of argument can be well-defined regardless of all that branch business. This is essentially because the differential $\mathrm{d}\theta$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.)

Comment: @Ken, Of course, if the path $\gamma:[t_0,t_1]\to\mathbb{C}$ lies in a simply connected domain $U$ of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, then a branch of the argument can be well-defined on $U$. Moreover, for any branch choice $\operatorname{Arg}$ of the argument on $U$, we can compute: $$\operatorname{Im}\left(\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\right)=\operatorname{Arg}(\gamma(t_1))-\operatorname{Arg}(\gamma(t_0)).$$ This is indeed the case for the two integrals in my answer, and then you may make use of this observation for a quicker computation.

Comment: @Ken, For the first integral, you may choose $\mathrm{Arg}$ to be the principal argument function $\arg$ and hence we get $$\mathrm{Im}\left(\int_{L_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{1}{2}+i(p+\varepsilon)\right)-\arg\left(\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)=\arctan(2(p+\varepsilon))-0.$$

Comment: For the second integral, you may choose $\mathrm{Arg}$ so that it takes values in $[0, 2\pi)$. (I.e., the branch cut is chosen as $[0,\infty)$.) Then $$\mathrm{Im}\left(\int_{L_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-1}\right)=\operatorname{Arg}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i(p+\varepsilon)\right)-\operatorname{Arg}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)=\left(\pi-\arctan(2(p+\varepsilon))\right) - \pi.$$

Comment: So we cannot use directly Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? We have to take arguments?

Comment: @Ken, You can also use FToC, but with a carefully chosen branches of the complex logarithm.

Comment: Thank you. Which branch should I choose and how? Please guide me.

Comment: Nice way to do it. Also even if the path did cross the branch of the $\log$ in the original formula (presumably meaning the principal definition), the undefined derivative there would have the specified limit, so it can be ignored integrating in this way.